# Modify jQuery and PHP code to pull through ID and text value into OPTION element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple SELECT menu:

```
<select class='form-control' id='builders' name='builder_id'>
    <option value="1">Oracle</option>
    <option value="2">SQL</option>
</select>
```

I want to use the ID from the first SELECT to change the contents of a second SELECT, with an ID of "regions"

This is the jQuery code that I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#builders').change(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    $.get("ajax_cats.php", {'builder_id': currentValue}, function(data) {
      var regions = $.parseJSON(data).fld_label;
      $('#regions').empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
        var regionOption = '<option value="'+regions[i]+'">';
        regionOption += regions[i];
        regionOption += '</option>';
        $('#regions').append(regionOption);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is the contents of *ajax_cats.php*

```
 $sql = "SELECT cats.fld_label
           FROM tbl_b_cats cats
          WHERE cats.fld_parent = ? 
       ORDER BY cats.fld_label";

/* initialise */
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

/* prepare */
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error, SQL query: $sql");
}

/* bind */
if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['builder_id'])) {
    throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error");
}

/* execute & store */
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

/* 404 for no results */
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
} else {

    $regions = array();

    /* get results */
    $stmt->bind_result($fld_label);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $regions['fld_label'][]   = $fld_label;
    }

    echo json_encode($regions);

}
/* free and close */
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

$conn -> close();
```

This works just fine. The thing I'm trying to work out, and can't, is how to change it so that instead of the 2nd SELECT containing the same value in the "value" and display sections of the option elements:

```
<select class="form-control" id="regions" name="regions">
    <option value="BLOB_NAV">BLOB_NAV</option>
    <option value="Insert">Insert</option>
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
</select>
```

Is how can I change the code so that I could get to e.g.

```
<select class="form-control" id="regions" name="regions">
    <option value="1">BLOB_NAV</option>
    <option value="2">Insert</option>
    <option value="4">Select</option>
</select>
```

This way when am doing processing based on the value of the "regions" select, I can use the internal ID instead of the text value.

I can see I need to change the PHP on the ajax file to:

```
 $sql = "SELECT cats.fld_label
              , cats.fld_id
           FROM tbl_b_cats cats
          WHERE cats.fld_parent = ? 
       ORDER BY cats.fld_label";

/* initialise */
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();

/* prepare */
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    throw new Exception("Error preparing statement: $stmt->error, SQL query: $sql");
}

/* bind */
if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['builder_id'])) {
    throw new Exception("Error binding parameter: $stmt->error");
}

/* execute & store */
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

/* 404 for no results */
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
} else {

    $regions = array();

    /* get results */
    $stmt->bind_result($fld_label, $fld_id);

    ...

    echo json_encode($regions);

}
/* free and close */
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

$conn -> close();
```

But then I am stuck on:

1. How to change the code on the ajax PHP file so that the $regions array contains the ID and the text value.
2. How to change the jQuery code so that it takes the ID and text value from the ajax PHP output and puts them in the right places in the `<option>` element

Comment: Instead of `$.get(` you can use `$.getJSON(`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP: Append to the result array an associative array for each record.

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $regions []= [
        'id'    => $fld_id,
        'label' => $fld_label
    ];
}
```

JS: Access fields of each JSON record.

```
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++) {
  var regionOption = '<option value="'+regions[i]['id']+'">';
  regionOption += regions[i]['label'];
  regionOption += '</option>';
  $('#regions').append(regionOption);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro! Fixed.